# For $f \in L^1(a,b)$ show there is a unique $g$ such that $\int_a^x g(t)\, dt = (\int_a^x f(t) \, dt)^2$

Tags: real-analysis

I encountered this problem in self-study (reviewing of absolute continuity) of Jones, *Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Space*, Ch 16 #30:

Assume $f \in L^1(a,b)$. Show that there exists a unique $g \in L^1(a,b)$ such that $$\int_a^x g(t) \, dt = \left( \int_a^x f(t) \, dt \right)^2$$

I have posted my own solution and would appreciated any comments about it's correctness, as well as any better ways to go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $g(x) = 2 f(x) \int_a^x f(t) dt$. $g \in L^1(a,b)$ since $f \in L^1(a,b)$ and $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$ is absolutely continuous, hence continuous and bounded on $[a,b]$.

Then we can rewrite the above as 
\begin{align*}
g(x) &= f(x) \int_a^x f(t)dt + \int_a^x f(t)dt \cdot f(x) \\
\frac{d}{dx}\int_a^x g(t)dt &= \frac{d}{dx} \left[ \left( \int_a^x f(t)dt \right)^2 \right] \\
\implies \int_a^x g(t)dt &= \left[ \left( \int_a^x f(t)dt \right)^2 \right]
\end{align*}

If $\bar{g}$ purports to be another such function, then the same calculation (in reverse) will show it it identical to $g$, hence $g$ is unique.

Comment: Technically you should also check the two expressions in your last equation are equal at some point $x$, but this is trivial because clearly both expressions are $0$ when $x = a$. I think yours is probably the most succinct proof one can find.

Comment: Thanks, technical details such as yours are helpful.